# Por que variáveis locais não recebem valores default pelo compilador Java ou pela JVM?

Tags: java, variáveis

Por que o compilador atribui valores *default* para atributos mas não o faz para variáveis locais?

```
public class Teste{            
    int a;

    public void metodo() {
        int b;
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro, [o que você chama de atributo na verdade é um campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

A resposta mais simples é que os criadores da linguagem decidiram assim e eles não precisam justificar porque o fizeram. Podemos tentar pensar nas motivações.

Imagino que entenda que é mais seguro dar um valor padrão para um campo, assim não corre o risco de pegar lixo na memória. Poderiam ter feito o mesmo com variáveis locais, e de certa forma fizeram.

Experimenta declarar a variável e não usar. Experimenta atribuir um valor separado, depois de declarar sem valor. O problema real é usar uma variável sem dar um valor específico. Nesses casos haveria uma inicialização sem necessidade, a não ser que o compilador fizesse uma otimização, o que me parece que deveria fazer, mas talvez só perceberam a utilidade disso depois e não quiseram correr o risco de mudar a semântica e quebrar algum código existente ou confundir o programador.

Foi considerado que quase sempre é um erro de lógica não inicializar a variável então preferiram sempre considerar um erro. Eu acho que deveria ser no máximo um *warning*. Eu acho indesejável, mas não obrigatório. Essa escolha provavelmente diminui a quantidade de *bugs* em um código, então pareceu um decisão interessante.

Provavelmente deveriam ter optado por não exigir em todos os casos, incluindo as variáveis de instância, mas aí o campo teria que ser inicializado no construtor obrigatoriamente, o que ficaria um pouco esquisito, e em muitos casos exigiria um construtor que hoje não é exigido.

Com essa mania das pessoas de usar *getters* e *setters* pode ser que não queira por no construtor ([está errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), e nem vou falar que usam estes métodos em exagero), o que aconteceria se o acesso ao campo acontecesse antes de usar o *setter*? Seria muito complicado, ou impossível para o compilador garantir que isto não iria ocorrer, aí poderia dar erro ou teria que diminuir a flexibilidade. Em código local é muito mais simples determinar se a variável foi usada sem inicializar. Algoritmo tem ordem clara e definida, estrutura de dados não tem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).